# Transformation-Matrix (Definition & explanation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

I have to do a proof ("Let V be a vector space with basis A, B, C. Show that $T_{AC} = T_{BC}T_{AB}.$

Well, I really don't know what is menat by $"T_{AB}"$ or something like this. I thought about the transformation of matrices.. But what exactly does this mean?

(In order to make the proof I should understand what it says :D )

Thank you very much for any sort of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably (read it in your notes/book) it means:

$\;T_{AB}:=$ the transition matrix from basis $\;A\;$ to basis $\;B\;$ = write each element of $\;B\;$ as a linear combination of elements of $\;A\;$ and take the coefficients matrix's transpose.

And likewise with the other ones.

Comment: Hey; so if $ T_{AB} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\-1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ on which vector are the vectors e1, e2 (standard-basis) mapped?

Comment: If you're using the usual definitions,  the vectors of the natural basis are mapped on $\;(1,-1)\;,\;(1,1)\;$ , resp.